# extracting nodevalue from a DOM tree

Tags: php, html, parsing, screen-scraping, web-scraping

I want the code below to echo the string found inside the equipped element.
Shouldn't this be working?

```
<?

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML('http://website.com');

    $elements = $doc->getElementByID("equipped");

     echo $elements->nodeValue . "\n";



    ?>
```

Comment: i have tried several different elements.. divs and spans mostly though

Comment: Shouldn't it be `loadHTMLFile`?

Answer (score 1):

When using `DOMDocument::getElementById()`, I'd suggest you to set the property `validateOnParse` to true, to assure the document is well formatted and the method will work properly.

If the content of the node is only text, you can try the `textContent` attribute. The `nodeValue` attribute value can vary depending on the element type.

It would look like this:

```
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->validateOnParse = true;
    $doc->loadHTMLFile('http://website.com');
    $element = $doc->getElementById("equipped");

    if (!is_null($element)) {
        $content = $element->nodeValue;

        if (empty($content)) {
            $content = $element->textContent;
        }

        echo $content . "\n";
    }
?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: seems like it should be working, but it's not.  i wonder if it's possible to see if the array is empty before we echo out the value

Comment: The thing is that the method `getElementById()` returns a single element. Is it throwing any exception? Is there anything in your error log?

Comment: More things you may check in your PHP installation: Is the libxml enabled? Are errors configured to be logged properly?

Comment: @fardjad You're right! It must be `loadHTMLFile()`. Otherwise, you'd need to give the HTML source code in a string to be parsed. Just updated my answer.